# How do you use Selenium Python and have it go through every select tag that is REQUIRED in a web page, and then always choose [1] or the first option?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, dynamic, drop-down-menu

The number of select dropdowns in the page can vary, depending on the number of files a user chooses to upload to the website (from 1 up to 12 or so). So basically, find a *required* select dropdown, and then after making the proper selection, move on or scroll down to the next div with a *required* dropdown until all dropdowns have their proper selection made so that form submission can move forward.

```
<select class="form-control" id="dynamic-id" required="">
    <option value="">[Choose Option]</option>
    <option value="random_value">ALWAYS SELECT ME</option>
</select>

...

<select class="form-control" id="dynamic-id" required="">
    <option value="">[Choose Option]</option>
    <option value="random_value">ALWAYS SELECT ME</option>
</select>
```

I tried doing it like this

```
try:
    required_dropdowns = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//select[@required]/option")

    print(len(required_dropdowns))

    for each_dropdown in required_dropdowns:
        required_dropdowns[1].click()
        time.sleep(2)

except:
    NoSuchElementException
    print("Could not find required dropdown"):
    time.sleep(2)
```

Output prints out 36 dropdowns but it selects the proper option only for the first one.

I would really appreciate any input on how to execute this.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the selenium code you've writtent to solve your problem?

Comment: Edited for clarity